# Why is there a running error on leetcode and no error on vs2019?

Tags: c++

i am sure the **stringToCharArray** function have some problem.but i do not know how to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY8rz.png)

```
char* stringToCharArray(string s)
{
    char* str = new char[s.size() + 1];
    s.copy(str, s.size() + 1);
    str[s.size()] = '\0';

    return str;
}
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    char* p = stringToCharArray(s);
    int len = 0;
    int prelen = 0;
    unordered_set<char>st;
    while ( (*p) != '\0')
    {
        while(st.insert(*p).second) {
            p++;
        }
        len = max(prelen, (int)st.size());
        prelen = len;
        st.clear();
        st.insert(*p);
        p++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `stringToCharArray` function, and the memory leak you get from it? You could use indexes instead of the pointer `p`, or iterators, or a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop, or `std::for_each`.

Comment: Also, in the inner loop you can go out of bounds of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

Why do they get an error and you do not? They are compiling with [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and you are not.

What is your error? `s.copy(str, s.size() + 1);` is copying s.size+1 characters from a string that is s.size long and the

```
while(st.insert(*p).second) {
            p++;
        }
```

seems wrong as well, "keep going as long as something is inserted" will probably run out of bounds on `p`.

Not to mention the memory leak from doing new with no paired delete...